# How to get column wise Rank in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have pivotted data like this:

```
Product   Site1_Price   Site2_Price   Site3_Price
-----------------------------------------------------
Item1             250           150           325
```

and I want result shown like this:

```
Product   Site1_Price   Site1_Rank   Site2_Price   Site2_Rank   Site3_Price   Site3_Rank   
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Item1             250            2           150            1           325       3
```

Comment: What have you tried? Posting something we can code against would go a long way to getting you an answer. I would suggest using ROW_NUMBER() or perhaps RANK or DENSE_RANK. It all depends on what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Here's a hint:   UNPIVOT, RANK, PIVOT.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**Table Value Constructor**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) to build an in-line table containing *all price fields of your table*. Then you can apply `ROW_NUMBER` or `RANK` window function on this table to get the rank of each field. Finally perform `UNPIVOT` to get all results in a single row:

```
SELECT Product, Site1_Price, Site1_Rank, Site2_Price, Site2_Rank, Site3_Price, Site3_Rank
FROM mytable
CROSS APPLY ( 
   SELECT [Site1_Rank], [Site2_Rank], [Site3_Rank]
   FROM (SELECT col, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY v) AS rnk
         FROM (VALUES (Site1_Price, 'Site1_Rank'), 
                      (Site2_Price, 'Site2_Rank'), 
                      (Site3_Price, 'Site3_Rank')) AS x(v, col)) AS src
   PIVOT (
         MAX(rnk) FOR col IN ([Site1_Rank], [Site2_Rank], [Site3_Rank])      
         ) AS pvt) AS t
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d1920/1)

Answer (score 1):

Unpivot the data, then use something along the lines of....

```
    ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Product, ORDER BY Price)
```

Alternatively, since you are only ranking the three sites, a workaround would be to use a CASE statement.  Example:

```
CASE
  WHEN Site1_Price > Site2_Price AND Site1_Price > Site3_Price
    THEN 3
```

You can figure out the rest of the logic there - not the best solutuion per se but will work .

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
    (Product varchar(5), Site1_Price int, Site2_Price int, Site3_Price int)
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (Product, Site1_Price, Site2_Price, Site3_Price)
VALUES
    ('Item1', 250, 150, 325)
;
Select product,
MAX([Site1_Price_1])[Site1_Price_1],
MAX([1]) Site1_Rank,
MAX([Site2_Price_2])[Site2_Price_2],
MAX([2])Site2_Rank ,
MAX([Site3_Price_3] )[Site3_Price_3] ,
MAX([3])Site3_Rank

FROM (
select product,
COL+'_'+CAST(ROW_NUMBER()OVER( order by col ) AS VARCHAR)COLL,
VAL,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER( order by val )RN,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER( order by col )RNN 
FROM @Table1
CROSS APPLY (values('Site1_Price',Site1_Price),
('Site2_Price',Site2_Price),
('Site3_Price',Site3_Price))cs(col,val))T
PIVOT (MAX(val) FOR RN IN ([1],[2],[3]) )P
PIVOT (MAX(RNN) FOR COLL IN ([Site1_Price_1],[Site2_Price_2],[Site3_Price_3]))PP
GROUP BY PP.Product
```